# Visual Studio 2017 Window 10. All of a sudden cannot connect to MAc

Tags: ios, xamarin, mono

I've not touched the Mac.
Nothing has changed IOS wise on my Visual Studio.

However, all of a sudden 2 days ago when I go to pair to Mac it fails wit the message........
"The Mon version isntalled on the Mac may not be compatible with this version of Visual Studio.  Would you like us to install Mono '5.18' for you?.  This will overwrite any existing Mono installations on the Mac."

Now as I have said, nothing on these 2 machines has changed as far as I know.

If I look at the logs, I see thye following lines......amongst others...

```
Xamarin.Messaging.Integration.State.ServerStateContext|Information|0|Checking Mono installation...
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner|Verbose|0|Executing SSH command 'printenv HOME'...
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner|Verbose|0|Executing SSH command **'which mono64'...
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner|Warning|0|Failed to execute 'which mono64': ExitStatus = 1**
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner|Verbose|0|Executing SSH command 'which /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono64'...
**Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommands|Information|0|A valid Mono installation has been found at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono64'**
Xamarin.Messaging.Ssh.SshCommandRunner|Verbose|0|Executing SSH command '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/bin/mono64
```

What could be my issue?  Is it the "Failed to execute 'which mono64'" part that is giving me my problems.
I don't want to update the Mac version of Mono if I can help it.

HELP.
I admit I am useless on a Mac bu the fact is nothing has changed that I am aware of so I 'm baffled as to why all of a sudden I cannot connect to the Mac.

**Here is my info from Viusal Studio 2017 (Win 10)**
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.9.7
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.7+28307.423
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03190

Installed Version: Community

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   8.14.20131.1
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017   15.9.04012.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2017

ASP.NET Core Razor Language Services   15.8.31590
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2017   5.2.60913.0
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   15.9.03024.0
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   15.9.02046.0
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

C# Tools   2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Extensibility Message Bus   1.1.49 (remotes/origin/d15-8@ee674f3)
Provides common messaging-based MEF services for loosely coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and integration.

JavaScript Language Service   2.0
JavaScript Language Service

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 - v2.9.0.0

Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   1.0
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Mono Debugging for Visual Studio   4.13.12-pre (9bc9548)
Support for debugging Mono processes with Visual Studio.

NuGet Package Manager   4.6.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

ResourcePackage Extension   1.0
ResourcePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

ResourcePackage Extension   1.0
ResourcePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

SQL Server Data Tools   15.1.61901.24070
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript Tools   15.9.20918.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   2.10.0-beta2-63501-03+b9fb1610c87cccc8ceb74a770dba261a58e39c4a
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools 10.2 for F# 4.5   15.8.0.0.  Commit Hash: 6e26c5bacc8c4201e962f5bdde0a177f82f88691.
Microsoft Visual F# Tools 10.2 for F# 4.5

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers

VisualStudio.Mac   1.0
Mac Extension for Visual Studio

Xamarin   4.12.3.80 (d15-9@914127c74)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin Designer   4.16.13 (45a16efd4)
Visual Studio extension to enable Xamarin Designer tools in Visual Studio.

Xamarin Templates   1.1.128 (6f5ebb2)
Templates for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps with Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin.Android SDK   9.1.7.0 (HEAD/ba9da7a76)
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   12.2.1.15 (d60abd1)
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Comment: The problem is not the "which mono64" failure, that is testing if there is a mono in the path (i.e. to override the "current" installed version), there is not, and thus it checks for it in the default install location (`/Library/Frameworks/Mono....`) and it finds it... Sounds like your Visual Studio version on your Windows PC got updated (install any system updates recently?)... Otherwise, what is the current installed version of Mono on your Mac? Someone run Visual Studio for Mac on it and accept an update prompt?

Comment: No updates to my Visual Studio.
Even got a colleague to try and he gets the same and he definately hasn;y updated his VS.

I am not aware of any changes on either (doen't mean they haven't happenned)>

On the MAc - mono --version gives me 5.16.021

Comment: Since the mac is reporting an "older" Mono version than that what is required from the Windows-based Xamarin, it is fairly easy to say, something on your Windows PC was updated.... (unless your Mac was "rolled back" to a prior version....)

Comment: Thanks.  Odd though, especially as it happens for the colleague too.
Can you clarify....this wouldn't be project/solution specific....this would be a change to the visual studio installation?

Comment: It would be dependent on the Xamarin MSBuild tasks (and iOS remoting) version installed within Visual Studio...

Comment: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>.\MSBuild.exe -version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.7.3190.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

4.7.3190.0
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/153117/updated-vs-mac-and-it-broke-xamarin-ios-vs-2017-for-windows

Comment: In the end - updated the Mono version to 5.18 as per the message.
Just didn't like the way it was forced upon me though. Not an Apple Fan ;)